# Excel Spreadsheets and Vlookups

Tags: excel, if-statement, vlookup, formulas

I have spent about 2 days now trying to copy and paste row by row...
I have about 69 out of 600.

My problem is this:  I have 2 Spreadsheets.  Spreadsheet 1 has the name of procedures 1-602.  In Spreadsheet 2 I have the same procedures followed by their corresponding duration times, and specialties.  Spreadsheet 2 however, is a master file so it has about 10,000 procedures.  I have to literally Ctrl Find the procedures from spreadsheet 1, then copy and paste the information following the name in A2:A6 or B2:B6.  I have tried IFError and Vlook up but it says that I am missing parts to my formula.  Is what I am trying to do possible?  What I want it to do is to look at the procedure name from Spreadsheet 1, find it in spreadsheet 2 and bring back that information on the rows behind it ei. A2:A6.

Comment: Pnuts I tried: =OFFSET('[Data Collection Workbook - SurgiNet® Procedures.xlsx]Surgical Procedures - Main OR'!$A$4, MATCH(A76, '[Data Collection Workbook - SurgiNet® Procedures.xlsx]Surgical Procedures - Main OR'!$A$4:$AE$602,0)+1, +2, +3, +4, +5, +6)

Comment: The layout of Sheet 1 is just A1:A159 (as I'm doing a section of the procedures first).  Sheet 2 is A4:AE602

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following, update the +0 to +1, +2, etc. to retrieve additional rows.

```
 =offset(sheet2!$A$1,match(Sheet1!A1,Sheet2!$a:$a,0)+0,0,1,1)
```

Comment: I tried: =OFFSET('[Data Collection Workbook - SurgiNet® Procedures.xlsx]Surgical Procedures - Main OR'!$A$4, MATCH(A76, '[Data Collection Workbook - SurgiNet® Procedures.xlsx]Surgical Procedures - Main OR'!$A$4:$AE$602,0)+1, +2, +3, +4, +5, +6) - But it said there were too many arguments :(

Comment: Indeed, use first `=OFFSET('[Data Collection Workbook - SurgiNet® Procedures.xlsx]Surgical Procedures - Main OR'!$A$4, MATCH(A76, '[Data Collection Workbook - SurgiNet® Procedures.xlsx]Surgical Procedures - Main OR'!$A$4:$AE$602,0)+0, 0,1,1)` to retrieve the first following row, then  `=OFFSET('[Data Collection Workbook - SurgiNet® Procedures.xlsx]Surgical Procedures - Main OR'!$A$4, MATCH(A76, '[Data Collection Workbook - SurgiNet® Procedures.xlsx]Surgical Procedures - Main OR'!$A$4:$AE$602,0)+1, 0,1,1)` for the second row, etc.

Comment: glad to help. Please accept the answer if it worked out for you, and welcome to SO.